# Get list of all products

Tags: magento

How do I get the store to list all products, independent of category?

Comment: What category from where you get this category please be more clear

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work in all Magento versions:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
//Magento does not load all attributes by default
//Add as many as you like
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
foreach($products as $product) {
//do something
}
```

Comment: $ missing at the first line.